# Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples.HelperCode does not compile

Tags: c#, azure, dynamics-crm, adal, dynamics-crm-online

I'm trying to use Microsoft's Dynamics CRM API helper code to connect to an Azure CRM instance and query some entities. The code is in package `Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples.HelperCode`.

However, the helper code provided by Microsoft fails to compile.

Here are the errors:

[image: MicroFail]

Has anyone managed to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you paste the error message instead of image, that will help to search & find this similar problem in future. If you find the answer helpful, pls upvote/mark it to encourage community volunteers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the old project using ADAL 2.x old version but conflicting with latest ADAL 3.x version in your system.

```
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(organizationUrl, clientcred);
```

Change the above line like below:

```
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ClientConfig.CRMOrgUrl, clientcred).Result;
```

[Reference](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/gustafscrmblog/archive/2017/09/15/authenticationresult-acquiretoken-deprecated-in-adal-3-x-and-how-to-fix)